# Redshift "permission denied for relation" even as SUPER user?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Data is sitting in 1 table and can be accessed easily enough :

```
select * from source.sales limit 100;
```

View is a straight 'select *'

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW processed."sales"  
AS    
SELECT * FROM source."sales"  WITH NO SCHEMA BINDING;
```

However, even a SUPER user gets denied :

```
SELECT * FROM processed."sales" limit 100
```

> ERROR: permission denied for relation sales

I am trying to figure out how a super user can be denied !?
The only thing that I am suspicious of, is that the views were created by 1 user, and owner changed using :

```
ALTER TABLE xxx OWNER TO xxx
```

. yet still unsure how/why that would break things ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late binding view runs with the privileges of the owner of the view.  Does the owner ("xxx") have access to the underlying table?  These rights need to be in place at the time of super-user query execution.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_VIEW.html

> To query a late binding view, you need select privileges for the late
> binding view itself. You should also make sure the owner of the late
> binding view has select privileges to the referenced objects

Being a super-user executing your query doesn't change the rights of the view.  This ability to inherit the rights of a view is how redshift implements fine grained security (row and column level).

Comment: Thanks Bill.
With regard to your last sentence ... is there an implication here that one's use of RBAC would heavily depend on the use of bound schemas ?

Comment: That's a great question. AFAIK RBAC roles and table level grants are independent systems of security (2 layers if you will). RBAC is fairly new and I haven't seen a good writeup on the interactions of these 2 systems. I BELIEVE that RBAC is enforced at query parsing and grants are applied at the database objects. Both need to allow an action for it to occur. So I think that if RBAC allows a user to access a late binding view then that user would allow the user to see the referenced data as long as the view owner has been granted. But what if the view owner doesn't have RBAC rights? Don't know.

Comment: My guess is that the late binding view owner's RBAC role has no affect on the view's privileges as this isn't a new query parsing.  But this is based on a heap of assumptions and guesses so a test case is needed.